# Setting Up Authorization For PayPal Express Checkout Payments

Tags: paypal, authorization, capture, authorize

Good Afternoon,

We are trying to set up our PayPal Express checkout to process PayPal payments by only authorizing the payments, giving us the option to then be able to either capture or void the payment from within our PayPal account. Have tried changing PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization, but this doesn't seem to be working. This code only allows the sale/payment to be taken straight away. Any help or suggestions, would be very much appreciated. Here's a link to the original code before we have applied any modifications:

https://github.com/wp-e-commerce/WP-e-Commerce/blob/branch-3.15.1/wpsc-merchants/paypal-express.merchant.php

Kind Regards,

Andy

Comment: You have to set =Authorization in multiple places, both the SetExpress and DoExpress.  It looks like that code will take the value from a config setting in the plugin's setting interface

Comment: Hi Preston. Firstly a big thank you for taking the time to reply with this information. Have set=Authorization in multiple places. Line 688 is set=Sale. Not sure if this needs changing at all. If I set it to authorization here instead of =sale, it throws an error. Kind Regards, Andy

Answer (score 0):

In order to do payments of type Authorization you need to:

1. Have "Authorization" set or evaluated from plugin settings everywhere (including line 688 in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment)
2. Have your User/PWD/Signature credentials set, using the information from your PayPal account in https://www.paypal.com/api .  Uncredentialed API calls can process Sales, but not Authorizations.

If at all possible you really should configure "Authorization" within the plugin's settings, and not by changing any code.

Comment: Hi Preston, again, a big thank you for all your help today. Unfortunately the plugin that we use doesn't have the option to configure things like "authorization" The only way we will be able to achieve this is by modifying the plugins code. Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: Hi Preston, can confirm that user/pwd/signature credentials are set from the information in our PayPal account. The error points to this line of code: $nvpstr = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&PAYERID=' . $payerID . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=' . $currCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . $BN . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM=" . urlencode( $sessionid ); Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: Well I don't know what the error is, but that code is fine.

Comment: Thanks Preston from the confirmation on the code being fine. Basically when we changed =sale to =authorization on this line of code it throws the error where our shopping cart can't display it's contents. Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: The only explanation I have for that is that it's not actually using your USER/PWD/Signature in the request--but can't say anything for sure without a detailed error log

Comment: Hi Preston, again, thank you for all your help today. I've fixed the error and can now get through to the PayPal express checkout and fill card details etc. After completing this process you are then re-directed back to the website to make the final call by clicking the "confirm payment" button. When you click the confirm payment button the page just refreshes. This points to the following code at line 959: $output .= " <p>  <input name='usePayPal' type='submit' value='" . __('Confirm Payment','wp-e-commerce') . "' /></p>\n";         Not sure if we need to add an extra code? Kind Regards, Andy

Comment: I don't know why it's just refreshing, but you need DoExpressCheckoutPayment.php to execute

Comment: Thanks Preston, Kind Regards, Andy